# What are the connotations of gentil?

Tags: sens

Wiktionary gives two definitions for *gentil*:

1. kind, nice
2. good (about children, in the sense of good boy/girl)

But under the usage notes, it says that the modern-day meaning is different, and sometimes even derogative. It claims that *gentil* can be a euphemism for boring.

Could someone please explain this further? Is *gentil* still used as a genuine compliment for adult or children? Or is it mostly used in an ironic way?

How would you use it yourself?

Comment: The fr wiktionary https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentil does not indicate this nowadays meaning. And I don't know it either (boring or similar). But there are some ironical usages and meanings (have a look at the 5, 6 and 7 entries in the link).

Comment: To quote "Le père noël est une ordure": "Je n'aime pas dire du mal des gens mais effectivement, elle est gentille"

Answer (score 3):

As DominiqueH wrote in his answer, the tone of voice is an indicator of wether "gentil" is used as a compliment or not.
As a French however, I never heard of it meaning "boring", but rather "dumb" or "stupid".
Still, if you say it honestly, people will usually not take it as an insult.

> "*Tu es tellement gentil avec moi!*" - "*You're so kind to me!*"

Note that same applies for "innocent" ("*il est innocent*" can mean "*he doesn't know what he's doing is stupid*" and "*he's stupid*" by extension) when used ironically.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it's a genuine compliment, but should be used with "très": il est très gentil.
Can sometimes mean "dumb, stupid", depending of the context and the tone of voice. "il est gentil, mais,,,"

Answer (score 1):

It only depends on the context, but as said @DominiqH adding "très" avoids any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

[In french but I can answer/translate in english]

L'idée derrière les connotations péjoratives de gentil provient des liens entre gentillesse et naïveté excessive et donc bêtise. Cependant, même quand on sous-entend que la personne dont on parle est stupide, dire qu'elle est gentille signifie tout de même qu'elle l'est au sens mélioratif ; c'est équivalent à "He is so kind that he is stupid."

En général, il est difficile de distinguer entre le pur compliment et la remarque plus péjorative. Le sens dépend particulièrement du contexte, mais certaines expressions ont une connotation plus marquée :

> Il est trop gentil.

Comme le "trop" indique un excès, cette expression indique que le sujet est si gentil qu'il se laisse faire, ce qui permet aux autres d'abuser de sa gentillesse. Ce n'est pas particulièrement péjoratif ; c'est plutôt un avertissement qui peut être adressé à la personne elle-même : "Tu es trop gentil, tu ne devrais pas te laisser marcher sur les pieds."

> Il est bien gentil.

Cette expression suggère fortement la bêtise. Par exemple, "Il est bien gentil, mais il n'a pas inventé le fil à couper le beurre." ; "Il est bien gentil, mais il n'est pas bien malin/fûté."

> Il est très gentil. Il est tellement gentil !

De cette façon, on indique seulement la gentillesse.

Enfin, une dernière remarque : j'ai aussi entendu, quoique rarement, l'expression "Elle est très gentille (avec les garçons/hommes)." pour signifier qu'une jeune fille ou une femme accordait facilement ses faveurs. Je ne saurais pas dire si c'est une signification répandue.